# Mongo Map Reduce vs sorting with PHP for a social newsfeed scenario

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce, nosql

I have my `collection` `SocialWall` and each user has its own `Document` each month with `Event` driven notifications.

My problem is that the `users` will want to get new notification based on the field `TS` in the `Event` object inside `SocialWall`. Effectively asking **Can you give me all the notification since TS?** (for the sake of the example lets pretend that `TS` is within the same month)

I have 1 choice to make here in order to give the user only what he/she wants.

*1) Do I fetch all the entire's Month from `SocialWall` and sort it in `PHP`?*

As the users friends increase and different interactions with the app increase that array will grow really quickly, as users will have lots of events. Thus, I will have to sort and filter by `TS` a huge array. This might not be the best for performance or memory management in great scale.

*2) Do I make a `Map Reduce` function and make `MongoDB` give me the sorted & filtered array?*

I've been reading around and there is a lot of commentary going on about `map reduce` not being very efficient. Yes, since `2.4` it has improved, but as a `new to Mongo` and `Map Reduce` (I have never done one before) I do not know what that really means in terms of performance. Thus, I am worry about creating a slow query that in turn will put more strain into my Mongo Server. Also I've been reading that a lot of people prefer to use `Hadoop` for their complex queries with `map reduce` in order to get the best performance.

I was wondering What is the current best solution for my problem? Should I go for sorting in `PHP` or make a `Map Reduce`?

If `Map Reduce` is the best solution, How could I go about it?

The document looks something like this

```
SocialWall 
{
_id: MongoId
userId: MongoId
Month: 1003(MonthYear)
Events:[]
}

Event
{
_id: MongoId
userId: MongoId
ts: ISODate
details:[]
likedBy:[]
comments:[]
}
```

Comment: a social wall is best done as one event per row with the entire wall posts detail in that wall so no join needed

Comment: @Sammaye you mean not having `SocialWall` and directly fetching from `Event`? But then I have to search in `event` by all the users friends's id to find their events. That will create lots more querying? also wouldn't that make my life hell if/when I need to start `Sharding`?

Comment: MongoDB isn't a great fit for some scenarios. This may be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the aggregation framework, it's more efficient for these purposes.

1. $project **userId** and **events**.
2. $unwind the **events** field
3. $match events which have **ts** higher than the one you want to compare
4. $sort by **ts**

This is way more efficient than sorting and filtering in PHP.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/
http://www.php.net/mongocollection.aggregate